# Plotting a graph with legends that don't overlap the graph?

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending

Consider:

```
tmax = 100;
b = 0.1;
n[t_] := S[t] + P[t]
SP = NDSolveValue[{
    S'[t] == (-b/n[t])*S[t]*P[t],
    P'[t] == (b/n[t])*S[t]*P[t],
    S[0] == 0.99,
    P[0] == 0.01},
   {S, P},
   {t, 0, tmax}];
Plot[{Through[SP[t]], Total@Through[SP[t]]} // Evaluate, {t, 0, tmax},
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Dashed}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style[Time, Black, FontSize -> 15], 
   Style[Density, Black, FontSize -> 15]}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"A(t)", "B(t)"}, {Right, Top}]]
```

How do I plot the legends such that it doesn't overlap? for different inputs the graph changes so is there an automatic way for it not to overlap?

Side questions:

i) How do I put a box around the legends after they've been fixed?
ii) How to insert extra parameter in legends without it being a graph in the plot?   
iii) How to put another dashed line at 0(and make the dashed lines both black in colour)?

**EDIT**(using Szabolcs's solution):

```
tmax = 100;
b = 0.2;
g = 0.2;
n[t_] := S[t] + P[t] + R[t]
SPR = NDSolveValue[{
    S'[t] == (-b/n[t])*S[t]*P[t],
    P'[t] == (b/n[t])*S[t]*P[t] - g*P[t],
    R'[t] == g*P[t],
    S[0] == 0.95,
    P[0] == 0.05,
    R[0] == 0},
   {S, P, R},
   {t, 0, tmax}];

{f1, f2, f3} = SPR;

st = Style[#, 15, Black] &;

Plot[{f1[t], f2[t], f3[t], f1[t] + f2[t] + f3[t], 0}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green, Directive[Black, Dashed], 
   Directive[Black, Dashed]}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> st /@ {"Time", "Density"}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{Blue, Red, Green, Black}, {"A(t)", "B(t)", 
     "C(t)"}, LegendFunction -> Framed], {0.85, 0.65}]]
```

We have overlapping; how can we place the legends automatically such that it doesn't overlap the graph?

**EDIT 2**

I manually shifted the legends and it worked fine.

Comment: Look up `PlotLegends` in the docs, specifically Scope -> Legend Placement -> last example.

Comment: Did you consider PlotLegends -> {"A(t)", "B(t)"} such that the legends are outside of the frame? That way they cant intercept with the plot.

Comment: @Szabolcs I want them in the plot, not outside.

Comment: The example I refer to shows how to put them inside as well.

Answer (score 3):

All the legend-related questions can be answered by looking at examples in the [`PlotLegends`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html) doc page. Generally, it is a good idea to look through the examples in the relevant documentation pages.

You can do something like this:

```
{f1, f2} = SP;

st = Style[#, 15, Black] &;

Plot[{f1[t], f2[t], f1[t] + f2[t], 0},
 {t, 0, tmax}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Directive[Black, Dashed], Directive[Black, Dashed]},  
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> st /@ {"Time", "Density"},
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[
   LineLegend[{Blue, Red, Black}, {"A(t)", "B(t)", "foo"}, LegendFunction -> Framed], 
   {0.85, 0.65}]
]
```

[image]

> How do I plot the legends such that it doesn't overlap?

Use scaled coordinates for the legend position. See the [`PlotLegends`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html) doc page, Scope -> Legend Placement.

> How do I put a box around the legends after they've been fixed?

See [`LegendFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LegendFunction.html). There are also several examples in the doc page of [`PlotLegends`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html) under Scope -> Legend content. Check them to see how to use different frame styles.

> How to insert extra parameter in legends without it being a graph in the plot?

Use an explicit legend specification. See e.g. [`LineLegend`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LineLegend.html).  There is an example with `SwatchLegend` in the [`PlotLegends`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html) doc page.

> How to put another dashed line at 0(and make the dashed lines both black in colour)?

There are several ways:

- Add constant functions to your plot, as in my example
- Use [`GridLines`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GridLines.html) with [`GridLinesStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GridLinesStyle.html).
- Use [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html) with [`InfiniteLine`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InfiniteLine.html).

As for making the existing dashed line in your plot black, use [`Directive`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Directive.html) to combine styles, as in my example.

Comment: your solution is nice, however for a slightly different inputs for a different  model results in overlapping the graph. Is there a way to reduce the size of the legends? also to place it automatically? Please look at my edit :)

Comment: @Maths No, there is no way to place it automatically in such a way that it will not overlap with the contents of the plot. The only way to ensure no overlap without manual intervention is to have the legend outside of the frame.

Comment: Personally, I did not find this to be a problem. If I am doing exploratory work, i.e. I make plots so that I can look at them myself, it is fine to have the legend outside. If I am making figures for a publication, I find it necessary to manually polish the figure anyway. A better positioning of the legend is just a small part of this. In my experience, making _high quality_ publication figures always takes some amount of manual work.

Comment: Agreed. is there a way to reduce the legend size then since they are rather oversized?

Comment: @Maths There are ways to tweak the spacing between legend entries, tweak the margin size, the font size, the legend marker size, so yes. I don't recall the syntax off-hand, I would have to check the docs, and I don't have time now. Please check the docs, and feel free to ask a separate question about the details you did not find (some of these tweaks are not that easy to make, as I recall).

Comment: @Maths I only just saw your edit. I think this is best asked as a separate question.

Comment: No worries, I fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

I like to use `Epilog` to insert graphics primitives exactly as I like them. For example:

```
Plot[{Through[SP[t]], Total@Through[SP[t]]} // Evaluate, {t, 0, tmax},
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Dashed}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style[Time, Black, FontSize -> 15], 
   Style[Density, Black, FontSize -> 15]},
 Epilog -> {Text["A(t)", {65, .25}], Text["B(t)", {70, .8}], 
   Dashing[.02], Line[{{0, 0}, {100, 0}}]}]
```

Produces:

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, however can you make the top line in black too? Also suppose I wanted to state another parameter on the side, how would I do it?

Comment: Also, since I have many different inputs for "b" in this example, so the labels aren't in the correct place, is there a way to do it automatically? For example, consider b=1.

Comment: To add a dashing line instead of the one you plotted at the top, delete it and add in the `Epilog` sequence a `Line[{{0,1},{100,1}}]`. As for placing the  "b" according to values, you just pass the values to the coordinates of the `Text[]` command after some adjustment, although it sounds like you want several "b" and I am not sure what you envision. You could add `Point[]` commands at the coordinates you want and put text near those.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

tmax = 100;
n[t_] := S[t] + P[t]
```

For "different inputs" use [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue.html)

```
SP = ParametricNDSolveValue[{S'[t] == (-b/n[t])*S[t]*P[t], 
    P'[t] == (b/n[t])*S[t]*P[t], S[0] == 99/100, P[0] == 1/100}, 
    {S, P}, {t, 0, tmax}, {b}];
```

Use [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) to see the effects of varying the parameter

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[
  {Through[SP[b][t]], Total@Through[SP[b][t]], 0} //
   Evaluate, {t, 0, tmax},
  PlotStyle ->
   {Blue, Red, {Black, Dashed}, {Black, Dashed}},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel ->
   (Style[#, Black, FontSize -> 15] & /@
     {Time, Density}),
  PlotLegends -> Placed[
    LineLegend[
     {"A(t)", "B(t)"},
     LegendLabel -> 
      StringForm["b\[ThinSpace]=\[ThickSpace]``", NumberForm[b, {3, 2}]]],
    {If[b >= 0.1, Right, Left], Center}]],
 {{b, 0.1}, 0.01, 1, 0.01,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Good answer. However, is there a way to remove the "$b$" parameter from the top of the graph? because I'll be using it in a document so it wont look 'good'. Also is the a way to name the $b$ as $b_0$?

Comment: The slider control is needed for the `Manipulate` so you can change the values of `b`. If you want its label to read `b0` change the control specification to `{{b, 0.1, Subscript["b", 0]}, ...}` to remove the label use `{{b, 0.1, ""}, ...}` (in either case, the `Appearance -> "Labeled"` is optional). Also change to `LegendLabel -> 
 StringForm["``\[ThinSpace]=\[ThickSpace]``", Subscript["b", 0], 
  NumberForm[b, {3, 2}]]`. To remove the panel add `Paneled -> False` to the `Manipulate`.